# Rails: process partials with loop, add additional class for the first item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I'm trying to implement some kind of image gallery. And I decided to use partials with an image snippet inside. For each image category the partail is added 5 times per page. Actually it's pretty easy:

```
# main page
.container
  .row
    .col-lg-12
      %h1.page-header Image Gallery
    - 5.times do
      = render partial: 'image'

# partial
.col-xs-6.col-md-2
  = link_to image_tag('http://placehold.it/128x128', class: 'img-responsive'), '#', class: 'thumbnail'
```

But the problem is the first div in a row should have an additional class `.col-md-offset-1` (I have an odd number of images per the page). I doubt this can be done inside the cycle. Does anyone know how this can be workarounded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an extension to @SteveTurczyn answer!

```
# main page
.container
  .row
    .col-lg-12
      %h1.page-header Image Gallery
    - 5.times do |index|
      = render partial: 'image', locals: {index: index}

# partial
- css_class = (index == 0) ? 'col-xs-6 col-md-2 col-md-offset-1' : 'col-xs-6 col-md-2'
%div{class: css_class}
  = link_to image_tag('http://placehold.it/128x128', class: 'img-responsive'), '#', class: 'thumbnail'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a parameter.

```
- 5.times do |x|
  = render partial: 'image', locals: {counter: x}
```

Your partial will have a local variable `counter` that you can test to see whether it's the first partial (equal to 0).